# How to Properly Send and Receive Express API Response with Angular 2

Tags: angular, http, express, heroku

Here is how I am receiving a response from an Express API call I am making from my Angular 2 application. In my component:

```
this.emailService.sendEmail(this.name, this.email, this.message)
                     .subscribe(
                       (res) => {
                         console.log("Success");
                         this.success = true;
                       },
                       (err) => {
                         console.log("Failure");
                         this.success = false;
                       }
                     );
```

In my email service sendEmail() function:

```
return this.http.post('/api/sendemail', data)
                    .map(res => res.json());
```

From my Express API, I am sending the email and sending a response like so with the [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) node module:

```
router.post('/sendemail/', (req, res) => {
...
server.send({
    text: "Sent from " + req.body.name + " message: " + req.body.message + " reply to: " + req.body.email,
    from: "email@gmail.com",
    to:   "email@gmail.com",
    subject: "test"
  }, function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Email failed to send.");
    } else if (message) {
      console.log(message);
      res.status(200).send("Email sent successfully.");
    }
  });
});
```

The email is being successfully sent every time, and a 200 status code is being returned (I see the response in my console and the Heroku console), but the console logs "Failure" regardless. Am I properly sending the response back to my application?

Comment: Can you try `res.sendStatus(200)` instead of `res.status(500).send("Email failed to send.");`? It seems your usage is deprecated: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus

Comment: I tried doing that previously and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like this.

```
res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Email sent successfully.'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
res.status(200).send("Email sent successfully.");
```

To:

```
res.status(200).send({message: "Email sent successfully."});
```

or

```
res.status(200).json({message: "Email sent successfully."});
```

or

```
res.status(200);
```